# Remove sub menus from the admin view for a plugin that registers a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I know there are 357,982 other posts about this BUT they all kinda lack something ie. an actual example that works for those of us who don't write 4,594,334 line of code every day.

SO - As it stands the scenerio is:

1. A plugin that registers a custom post type
2. A sub-menu you want to hide

What next?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found is actually pretty easy and requires a bit of inspection of the source and a good understanding of what to look for.

In this example woocommerce is registering the custom post type 'product' with a sub-menu that appears as 'Product Options'. We want to hide this for non-admin users.

Doing an inspection of the menu items we find that the hyperlink for the parent menu is 'edit.php?post_type=event_ticket' - looking a little further we see that the hyperlink for the sub-menu is 'https://websitename.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes'

We will use the 'add_action' hook as shown below. Please note that we are using the url for the parent menu however we are ONLY using the page parameter for the child.

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu_pages', 999);

```
function remove_menu_pages()
{
    if (current_user_can('manage_options') == false)
    {
        //1st parameter is parent URL | second is the 'page' parameter from the child url 
        remove_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=product', 'product_attributes');

    }
}
```

Add this to your functions.php and then login as a non-admin user and the submenu should now be hidden.